# Search using multiple criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have two textboxes I want to search a table. I am putting the search through a query which I believe to be the issue. the code should take the criteria from both textboxes and search one table. after that the rest of the textboxes will fill with the recordset the is closest to the search.

I get a error at `RstRecSet.MoveLast` I get a compile error that says no current record. I do have a record like what I type into the box its not picking it up though

When I add in the exact name of the record it finds it no problem. It's almost as if it's treating the like operator as if it were a =.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command514_Click()
'DoCmd.Close
'DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContacts", acNormal
    Set RstRecSet = Nothing
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim searchNum As String
    Dim searchName As String
    searchNum = txtGroupNr
    searchName = txtGroupName
 On Error Resume Next
If IsNull(txtGroupNr) Or txtGroupNr = "" Then

        Me.txtGroupName.BackColor = vbRed
        Forms!frmGroupHeader!txtGroupNr.SetFocus

    Else
        'strSearchICN = txtGroupNr
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Me.txtGroupName.BackColor = vbWhite
        Set RstRecSet = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblGroupHeader Where GroupNum  Like '" & searchNum & "' And GroupName  Like '" & searchName & "';", dbOpenDynaset)
        RstRecSet.MoveLast
        intMaxCount = RstRecSet.RecordCount
        RstRecSet.MoveFirst
      ' Exit Sub
   End If

     If RstRecSet.EOF Then


        Me.txtGroupName.BackColor = vbRed
        Forms!frmGroupHeader!txtGroupNr.SetFocus

    Else
       Call DisplayFields

    End If
End Sub
```

**Here is the solution**:

```
    Private Sub Command514_Click()
'DoCmd.Close
'DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContacts", acNormal
    Set RstRecSet = Nothing
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim searchGroup As String
    Dim searchName As String

If IsNull(txtgroupSearch) Or txtgroupSearch = "" Then

        Me.txtGroupName.BackColor = vbRed
        Forms!frmGroupHeader!txtGroupNr.SetFocus

    Else
        'searchNum = txtGroupNr
        searchGroup = txtgroupSearch

        Set db = CurrentDb
        Me.txtGroupName.BackColor = vbWhite
        Set RstRecSet = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblGroupHeader Where groupName like '*" & searchGroup & "*' or groupNum like '*" & searchGroup & "*';", dbOpenDynaset)
            If RstRecSet.EOF And RstRecSet.BOF Then
            MsgBox ("NO RECORDS!")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        RstRecSet.MoveLast
        intMaxCount = RstRecSet.RecordCount
        RstRecSet.MoveFirst
      ' Exit Sub
   End If

     If RstRecSet.EOF Then
        Me.txtGroupName.BackColor = vbRed
        Forms!frmGroupHeader!txtGroupNr.SetFocus

    Else
        Call DisplayFields

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And people wonder how SQL Injection is still the number 1 security risk....

Comment: I get a error at RstRecSet.MoveLast i get a compile error that says no current record. I do have a recor like what i type into the box its not picking it up though.

Comment: First I'd like to thank everyone who's responding and helping me out, I really appreciate it. responding to HansUp, I added Option Explicit which helped my find errors in my sql query. Unfortunetly, I get the same run time error "No current record".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your SQL. The error suggests that you have no records. Before calling .MoveLast on the recordset you could put in a quick test with:

```
If RstRecSet.EOF and RstRecSet.BOF Then 
    msgbox("NO RECORDS!")
    exit sub
End if
```

Back to the SQL. You wrote `"Select * from tblGroupHeader Where GroupNum and GroupName Like '" & searchNum & GroupName & "';"` which, if you chose "1" as the GroupNum and "Physics" as the Groupname, would come out to something like `Select * from tblGroupHeader Where GroupNum and GroupName Like '1Physics';` Which makes no sense

Instead: `"Select * from tblGroupHeader Where GroupNum Like '" & searchNum & "' and GroupName Like '"  & GroupName & "';"` Which would look like `Select * from tblGroupHeader Where GroupNum Like '1' and GroupName Like 'Physics';`

I've found it helpful to put my SQL into a variable first and then write that variable to the Immediates window with a Debug.Print SQL so that I can just copy and paste back into my database to make sure that everything makes sense.

Comment: Hey JNevill,

Thanks for the repsponse, it was very helpful. I feel like we are getting closer to a solution. The block of code you wrote works however it just replaces the runtime error with a messagebox. I am typeing in a record i know is there but it's not picking it up for some reason.

When I add in the exact name of the record it finds it no problem. it's amost as if it's treating the like oprator as if it were a =.

Comment: Did you check your SQL statement as well? That, I believe, is the heart of your problem.

Comment: Here's my query, I don't see an issue but maybe I'm missing somthing.


db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblGroupHeader Where GroupNum  Like '" & searchNum & "' And GroupName  Like '" & searchName & "';", dbOpenDynaset)

Comment: Do you actually have a value for both searchNum and searchName that point to a specific record? Should that AND be an OR? Are you trying to a wildcard search instead of just an '=', which is all your LIKE is doing at the moment... Perhaps you mean `GroupNum like '" & searchNum & "' OR GroupName like '*" & searchName & "*';"`  - The problem is still in your SQL statement since you are bombing the code when it gets no records.

Comment: So weird, still treating the like as an =.

Comment: A `like` is almost exactly like an `=`, with a couple of differences. The most notable being that you can stick wildcards in the `like`. Without the wildcard, you might as well just use an =.

Comment: Right, currently the program will not find JNevill if i type in the search box JN which it should, right?

Comment: It should find that if the WHERE statement is written as `GroupNum like '" & searchNum & "' OR GroupName like '*" & searchName & "*';"`... Assuming that JNevill is a GroupName in your table. If it's written with an `AND` instead, then you would also have to include the exact GroupNum for JNevill.

Comment: Oh wow! you're the best man! Thats what I was missing; the little * things. I changed around my form so i have a group search box where you can search the number or the name not both. Thanks a ton!